# Storeing weighing scale data some where in memory and put that data any where on some key press

Tags: asp.net, winforms, web-services

I Have a weighing machine and a window application to read the input of weighing machine. now i want to store the input data some where in memory and retrieve the data from memory to web application at some key press.
As far now i am using clipboard to store and retrieve data but it stops the copy paste process of system .

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you be clearer? Are you currently receiving data from the scales via the clipboard? If so you need to find a way of interacting directly with the hardware - for that we need code and device details.

Comment: Yes I have a window application by which I am reading the weight and displaying the weight in textbox.But I want that value to be displayed in web application .some one suggested me to create a wcf service and read data of window application and display it in web application through java script.but I want to store that data some where in system cache and by clicking the web app text box and by pressing some key retrieve that value from system cache or another way

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the value available to an application and want that stored so that it can be retrieved within a web application.

You need a common place to store this data. Your web application is better off handling this as getting your forms application to link to your web application is much simpler then the other way round.

The simplest solution is a common database which your forms and web application both link to independently. Your forms app saves the value, and your web app retrieves it.

That is not always possible or securable. Depending on what technology your web application uses, expose a web service. You've hinted at wcf but if your web app is asp.net then I'd go with web API. You create a web service method that the forms application can call via a service reference or http request. That method can store the data within your web application. If your forms app still needs the data,mcreate another service method to get the data. Look up restful services with web API for more details.

The second approach also opens up the choice on storage, since you have one system managing the data storage, you can choose if that should be database, file or memory to suit.

Comment: yes i am using asp.net or both web and window application.

Comment: Earlier i saw a window software in which he is reading weight and configured such a way that when we press enter key any where it pastes the weight there, eg.notepad,word or any webapp.I also want to do something like that...

Comment: You can't target a paste into an application from yours. You can only put it on the clipboard for that application to paste from.